# Viewing History on GitHub

Tags: github

Is there a way on GitHub Desktop or GitHub Enterprise to see only my changes?  Currently, if I create a branch (call it Branch B) from Branch A, make changes to Branch B, and look at the history, I see everything on Branch A that was done before creating my branch.  I only want to see the changes I have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view your commits in by adding `author={username}` as a query param in the URL when you view all the commits on the GitHub repo as below

```
https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{branch}?author={username}
```

So https://github.com/facebook/react/commits/master would list down all commits on the **master** branch of **react** repo on GitHub and https://github.com/facebook/react/commits?author=gaearon would list down all commits of the user `gearon` on the same branch of the repo on GitHub.